# Left Outer Join with multiple Data tables

Tags: c#, linq, datatables-1.10

I have 3 DataTables

**DataTable1**

```
Id  Version     URL     Owner
1   1           "xx"    "alice" 
2   1           "yy"    "bob"
3   1           "zz"    "Mike"
4   1           "ww"    "Rob"
5   1           "ww"    "Bick"
```

**DataTable2**

```
Id  Version     DomainID    Region      Type
1   1           aa          asia        1
2   1           bb          europe      2
3   1           cc          africa      1
4   1           dd          aus1        0
```

**DataTable3**

```
Id  Size    FreeSpace
aa  2500    2000
bb  3300    3000
cc  5500    50
```

**Expected Join**

```
Id  Version     URL     Owner       DomainID    Region      Type    Size    Freespace
1   1           "xx"    "alice"     aa          asia        1       2500    2000
2   1           "yy"    "bob"       bb          europe      2       3300    3000
3   1           "zz"    "Mike"      cc          africa      1       5500    50
4   1           "ww"    "sean"      dd          aus1        0       null    null    
5   1           "ww"    "Bick"      null        null        null    null    null
```

I am doing a Join Operation on these tables using Linq as follows:

```
// Datatable1 joins with Datatable2 on Id and version (datatable1)  -->  Id and version (datatable2) 
   // Datatable2 joins with Datatable3 on DomainId(datatable2) --> Id(datatable3)


var result = from dataRows1 in DataTable1.AsEnumerable()
                             join dataRows2 in DataTable2.AsEnumerable() on

                             new
                             {
                                 Id = dataRows1.Field<long>("Id"),
                                 Version = dataRows1.Field<long>("version")
                             } equals new
                             {
                                 Id = dataRows2.Field<long>("Id"),
                                 Version = dataRows2.Field<long>("version")
                             }
                              into tempJoin
                              from datarowc in tempJoin.DefaultIfEmpty() 
                             join dataRows3 in DataTable3.AsEnumerable() on                  
         dataRowsc.Field<long>("DomainId") equals dataRows3.Field<long>("Id")
    select new

    {
    datarow1,
    datarowc,
    datarow3
    }
```

I am getting an exception of datarowc to be null. 
Not quite sure why datarowc is null here and how to achieve the expected join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;

namespace CodeWars
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            var result = datarows1.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(x => new
                    {
                        Tab1Row = x,
                        Tab2Row = datarows2.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(
                            y => x.Field<int>("Id") == y.Field<int>("Id") &&
                                x.Field<int>("Version") == y.Field<int>("Version")
                        )
                    }
                )
                .Select(x => new
                    {
                        Tab1Row = x.Tab1Row,
                        Tab2Row = x.Tab2Row,
                        Tab3Row = datarows3.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(
                            y => x?.Tab2Row?.Field<string>("DomainId") == y.Field<string>("Id")
                        )
                    }
                );
        }

        static DataTable datarows1 = new DataTable
        {
            Columns = {
                    { "Id", typeof(int) },
                    { "Version", typeof(int) },
                    { "URL", typeof(string) },
                    { "Owner", typeof(string) },
                },
            Rows = {
                    { 1, 1, "xx", "alice" },
                    { 2, 1, "yy", "bob" },
                    { 3, 1, "vv", "mike" },
                    { 4, 1, "ww", "rob" },
                    { 5, 1, "zz", "bick" },
                }
        };

        static DataTable datarows2 = new DataTable
        {
            Columns = {
                    { "Id", typeof(int) },
                    { "Version", typeof(int) },
                    { "DomainID", typeof(string) },
                    { "Region", typeof(string) },
                    { "Type", typeof(int) },
                },
            Rows = {
                    { 1, 1, "aa", "asia", 1 },
                    { 2, 1, "bb", "europe", 2},
                    { 3, 1, "cc", "asia", 1},
                    { 4, 1, "dd", "aus1", 0},
                }
        };

        static DataTable datarows3 = new DataTable
        {
            Columns = {
                    { "Id", typeof(string) },
                    { "Size", typeof(int) },
                    { "FreeSpace", typeof(int) },
                },
            Rows = {
                    { "aa", 2500, 2000 },
                    { "bb", 3300, 3000 },
                    { "cc",5500, 50},
                }
        };

    }
}
```

.Join() performs inner join, but you want left outer join, so forget about .Join()
Code I've provided gives you the result you expect. But maybe you need to add one more Select to form datastructure you need.

Comment: works beautifully, thanks a lot !! :-) . your input on using join vs select is really helpful.

Comment: Cool that I've been helpful :) 
P.S. Make the world better - never use tables  if you can use classes :) IDE helped me 0 (ZERO!!!) times while I wrote the linq conditions with tables!